# CefSharp Autoplay in Version 83.4.20

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium

In Version 71 of CefSharp's Chromium in WPF there was an option to enable autoplay when calling

```
Using CefSharp;

public static void Init(AbstractCefSettings settings)
{
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs["autoplay-policy"] = "no-user-gesture-required";
}
```

But `AbstractCefSettings` seem to not exist anymore or are moved to somewhere else and I can't find where it moved to or what it was replaced by.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply

```
public static void Initate(CefSettings settings)
{
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs["autoplay-policy"] = "no-user-gesture-required";
}
```